# Unable to run ./start.sh in terminal of VS Code, instead it just opens the file for editing

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, shell

I have a file called `start.sh` in the explorer tab of VS code. When I go to the terminal in VS Code it loads up the power shell terminal as the default. When I go to the directory where the file is `cd ...` and later type in `./start.sh` it does not run the script, and instead opens the file in my editor. Does anyone know why on Windows this happens?

Comment: Probably in Windows' file association settings you associated the file with an editor instead of associating it with a shell, and you are using cmd or PS and not bash.

Comment: It's associated to VS Code, so what should it be associated with?

Comment: The Linux shell that you use for your project, for example Git Bash. But if you use Git Bash, it would be easier to set that as shell for your terminal in the first place.

Comment: I thought the WSL would work here, but clearly not. The project is part of a course, so no need to version control. I have installed it anyway and is now working. Thank you.

Comment: Yes WSL would have worked too. You can use the button in the bottom left of VSCode to open a new Window in WSL remote mode.